# groovy method to check if password field contains at least 1 capital character, 1 numeric character and 1 special character

Tags: groovy

How do I write a function which returns `true` if the string contains at least 1 capital character, 1 numeric character and 1 special character in groovy?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You open `groovyConsole` and a web browser and start trying.

Comment: Oh yeah sure! Test driven development, isn't it?... get real

Comment: If the downvotes are due to the fact that you shouldn't have password requirements like this, I think it's unfair. We're here to learn. It's ok that the OP didn't already know this, now he learned why it's a bad idea. Also consider that he might not be in charge of the requirements.

Comment: @rlovtang agreed, even if the requirement will give bad usability, it doesn't mean it's a bad question or that the question should be closed.  The question is phrased clearly and has a definitive answer (or a number of valid answers).  It's fine for people to suggest alternatives, but we shouldn't punish people because we don't like their requirements or technology.  If we did, all of the ClearCase questions would be closed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`find`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#find%28java.lang.String%29) to independently test for the stated components of your requirement

```
def isValid (pwd) {
    return pwd.find(/[A-Z]/) && pwd.find(/\d/) && pwd.find(/[@#$%^&+=]/)
    //              or insert your 'special characters' here ^
}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Please don't do it.

Asking the user to use some set of compulsory characters just for his password to be "strong", instead of being easy to remember, is a very bad idea.

Please read [this XKCD comic](https://xkcd.com/936/) and reconsider your design.

---

### Update

If you *really* need to do this (maybe the question has nothing to do with passwords), you should check for uppercase letters using the [unicode regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) `/\p{Lu}/` or [`Character.isUpperCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase%28char%29) instead of `/[A-Z]/`, as there are many more uppercase letters than those on the English language.

```
SPECIAL_CHARS = '.,-_' as List // Change this list as needed.

def isValid(str) {
    def hasUpperCase   = str.find(/\p{Lu}/)
    def hasDigit       = str.find(/\p{N}/)
    def hasSpecialChar = str.any { it in SPECIAL_CHARS }
    hasUpperCase && hasDigit && hasSpecialChar
}

assert !isValid('asd')
assert !isValid('Asd')
assert !isValid('Asd1')
assert  isValid('Asd1.')
assert !isValid('correct horse battery staple')
assert  isValid('Σ.९')
```

Comment: May be a good idea, but not a correct answer. Consider porting to comment?

Comment: @paislee I've now updated the answer to be "correct". But I'll also leave the comment of it being a bad idea as my original answer. I understand that it might not be correct in the sense that it does not respond to the OP question, but in this case not doing what is asked is the right way to go. And I wouldn't like seeing an answer that only responds to what is asked without telling that it is a bad idea being accepted.

Comment: +1 for using unicode regex. Far too many developers believe the world is only A-Z.